# How do I copy a list of folders recursively, ignoring errors?

Tags: macos

I want to copy a bunch of folders recursively. However, I don't want one error preventing the copy from finishing. Is there any way to do a recursive copy(cp -R), ignoring (but logging) all errors produced? I'm on Mac OS X, but I assume the answer would be the same for *nixes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check out [rsync](http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html). It can do a more reliable job and only copy the files that didn't copy the first time:

```
rsync -vza --progress /source/ /destination/
```

Comment: Absolutely exactly what I needed, with a springling of `--exclude="<globpattern>"` and `--delete` to keep a try perfectly synched from one project to the next.

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer: [ditto(1)](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ditto.1.html)

Comment: Please share it here so that future people can learn..

Comment: I did share the answer... it is `ditto`. Syntax: `ditto <src dirs> <dst dir>`

Comment: Odd; when I first viewed this it was a broken image.

Comment: You did the right thing by following-up on your question once you found the info, but "answers" that consist only of a link are not future-proof; it's best to *embed* the information. (Acknowledging here, it's years later... but that's my point. Google sends people here. )

Comment: Updated link (tho it's just a man page): https://web.archive.org/web/20100722111116/http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ditto.1.html